# How to fix isInteger for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm no JS expert but I need to fix the following to work in IE. Issue is debugger throws: "Object doesn't support property or method 'isInteger'"

```
  function flattenFilters(link, page) {
        current_page = Number.isInteger(page) ? page : 1; // reset page to initial if not passed in
        var filters = link.data('filters'),
            string = '[property_overview sorter=on sorter_type=none pagination=off per_page=12 ';
        string += filters;
        string += ' sale_status=';
        string += (window.location.href.indexOf("sold-properties") > -1) ? "Sold" : "Sale,Auction";
        string += ' starting_row=';
        string += getStartingRow();
        string += ' template=custom-grid]';
        return string;
    }
```

Comment: See the polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger

Comment: It's not supported in IE11. Use polyfill instead.